# Javascript : Extract validation object from Form configuration

Tags: javascript

I am developing a dynamic form in react where the Form config data is defined in in the following format

```
let formConfig =  [
  //Row 1
  [
     //Column 1
    {
      code: "firstName",
      type: "text",
      required: true,
      validation: {
        type: "text",
        minLen: 4,
        maxLen: 20,
      },
    },
    //Column2
    {
      code: "lastName",
      type: "text",
      required: true,
      validation: {
        type: "text",
        minLen: 4,
        maxLen: 20,
      },
    },
  ],
  //Row 2
  [
    {
      code: "email",
      type: "email",
      required: true,
      validation: {
        type: "email",
      },
    }
   
  ],
];
```

I need to find an easy way to extract the validation data from all the fields. I have tried to use Array map function , but it looks like not the correct way to do this.

The expected result is ,

```
    {
      "firstName": {
      "validation": {
        "type": "text",
        "minLen": 4,
        "maxLen": 20
       }
     },

    "lastName": {
       "validation": {
          "type": "text",
          "minLen": 4,
          "maxLen": 20
        }
     },
     "email": {
        "validation": {
          "type": "email"
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could achieve this with the the following code

```js
let formConfig =  [
  //Row 1
  [
     //Column 1
    {
      code: "firstName",
      type: "text",
      required: true,
      validation: {
        type: "text",
        minLen: 4,
        maxLen: 20,
      },
    },
    //Column2
    {
      code: "lastName",
      type: "text",
      required: true,
      validation: {
        type: "text",
        minLen: 4,
        maxLen: 20,
      },
    },
  ],
  //Row 2
  [
    {
      code: "email",
      type: "email",
      required: true,
      validation: {
        type: "email",
      },
    }
   
  ],
];

let formData = formConfig
      .flat() //Rows
      .reduce(
        //Column fields
        (obj, field) =>
          Object.assign(obj, {
            [field.code]: {
              validation: field.validation,
            },
          }),
        {}
      );
   
console.log("FormData : ",formData);
```

Comment: You have an array of arrays hence one `.flat()` is enough.

Comment: Because there's a `required: ...` property (which would be totally useless when its value is always `true`) you might want to add a filter to only grab those objects that are required.

Comment: Yes. Super. Thank you . Removed the extra flat method

Comment: This was a learning I did recently. That is the reason I have shared both the question and answer here. But wondering why is the down vote for my question ?.. Is that bad ?